# SQL- Trying to subtract date values from the same column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I need a subtraction of a max date to the last previous status date and cannot figure it out. I will be using FindingID and UpdatedEstimatedRemediationDate.

For example:

FindingID 'FND-5645' has been updated 3 times:

```
UpdatedEstimatedRemediationDate
--------------------------------
NULL
2015-06-15
2015-12-30
2016-06-30
```

I need to get the days difference from June 30, 2016 from December 12,2015. I am using SQL Server 2008 R2. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to partition by `FindingId` and order by `UpdateDate` desc, pick first and last dates and have the date diff in days:

**Setup:**

```
-- drop table UpdatedEstimatedRemediationDate
create table UpdatedEstimatedRemediationDate
(
    FindingId INT,
    UpdateDate DATE
)

insert into UpdatedEstimatedRemediationDate values 
(1, '2015-06-15'), (1, '2015-12-30'), (1, '2016-06-30'), (2, '2015-07-13'), (2, '2016-05-01')
GO
```

**Query:**

```
;WITH Cte AS (
    SELECT FindingId, UpdateDate, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FindingId ORDER BY UpdateDate DESC) AS RowNo
    FROM UpdatedEstimatedRemediationDate
)
SELECT LU1.FindingId, DATEDIFF(day, LU1.UpdateDate, LU2.UpdateDate) AS DaysDiff
 FROM Cte LU1
    JOIN Cte LU2 ON LU2.FindingId = LU1.FindingId AND LU1.RowNo = 2 AND LU2.RowNo = 1
```

**[no self join version]**

For `SQL Server 2012`, `SELF JOIN` may be avoided using `LAG/LEAD` function:

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT FindingId, DATEDIFF(day, UpdateDate, LEAD(UpdateDate, 1, NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY FindingId ORDER BY UpdateDate)) DayDiff,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FindingId ORDER BY UpdateDate DESC) RowNo 
FROM UpdatedEstimatedRemediationDate)
SELECT CTE.FindingId, CTE.DayDiff
FROM CTE 
WHERE RowNo = 2
```

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly, this is basically an aggregation query with `datediff()`:

```
select findingid, datediff(day, min(UpdatedEstimatedRemediationDate), max(UpdatedEstimatedRemediationDate)
from t
group by findingid;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon Linoff, but that gives me the days between the absolute MIN and MAX, when I need last 2 most recent update dates calculated. So, I would need my results to show 183 days since it should calculate between 12-30-15(instead of the MIN) and 06-30-16